# Constantly getting 'Path already exists' error with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn

I have recently installed Subversion 1.6.15 and the latest TortoiseSVN on my machine. I am running Windows XP with a local XAMPP setup. I got things going early on with a few test folders and files and everything was smooth.

That is until just now.

To give you an idea of my problem:

- I go into the svn repository directory, create a new folder named: "file"
- I right click on the folder and select "create repository here" (no issue). I get confirmation message everything was successful.
- I go to my XAMPP htdocs desired directory named 'file-test', right click and select 'import'
- When it prompts for my repository URL, I enter: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/svn/file
- Once I hit ok, I am prompted with the error:

> ERROR    Path 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/svn/file' already exists

what the hell is going on?